# Extracting the hour from a datetime64[ns] variable

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a column that I've converted to datetime using pandas so it's now in the format datetime64.

```
LOCAL_TIME_ON 
2014-06-21 15:32:09
2014-06-07 20:17:13
```

I want to extract the hour to a new column. The only thing I've found that works is below, however, I get a SettingWithCopyWarning. Does anyone have a cleaner way I can do this?

```
TRIP_INFO_TIME['TIME_HOUR'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(TRIP_INFO_TIME['LOCAL_TIME_ON']).hour.astype(int)
```

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   '''
> ```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this:

```
TRIP_INFO_TIME['TIME_HOUR'] = TRIP_INFO_TIME['LOCAL_TIME_ON'].dt.hour
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks!